# How to test local application's UI using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, iphone

I have opened an application using `window.location = "Recipes://"`. from my ios. I wants to perform some ui element tests on this application using JavaScript. Since the application has opened in a separate window I could not perform any ui tests on it from my html page.

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    window.location = "Recipes://";
    /*var target = UIATarget.localTarget();
    target.frontMostApp().navigationBar().rightButton().tap();
    target.frontMostApp().keyboard().typeString("Myrecipe\n");
    target.frontMostApp().navigationBar().rightButton().tap();
    target.frontMostApp().mainWindow().tableViews()["Empty list"].buttons()["choosePhoto"].tap();
    target.frontMostApp().mainWindow().tableViews()["Empty list"].cells()["Nature,   (13)"].tap();
    target.frontMostApp().mainWindow().tableViews()["Empty list"].cells()["Photo, IMG_0026"].images()["Photo, IMG_0024"].tapWithOptions({tapOffset:{x:0.59, y:0.58}});
    target.frontMostApp().navigationBar().rightButton().tap();
    target.frontMostApp().navigationBar().leftButton().tap();*/
</script>
```

Comment: What sort of 'tests' ?

Comment: If the recipes app is a native app (obj-c), you won't be able to test it from a Safari window.

Comment: I tried to open recipes in a UIWebView class object. But it opened in separate window. Is there any  way to fire events on the UI elements without using xcode default UI automation tool.